# I can't set setOnClickListener on my button in Android

Tags: java, android, button

I'm making an Android app where I want to implement click events for buttons.
Here is my code for a button event. This code is implemented in onCreate() for an activity.

```
    DeclineBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.declineBTN);
    DeclineBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "button clicked NICE!!!");
        }
    });
```

When ever this activity load i get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Here is my xml for the view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".OpenTokActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/subscriberview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/loadingSpinner"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/publisherview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:keepScreenOn="true">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/declineBTN"
        android:background="@drawable/hangup"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you

Comment: please post the whole oncreate method

Comment: Post your activity code..

Comment: alternatively you can set an onclick directly in the xml for the button (android:onClick="declineBTN") and then in the activity add (public void declineBTN(View v) { ...code... })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);` before searching for the button with `findViewById`. In practice, your code should look like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);
Button DeclineBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.declineBTN);
DeclineBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "button clicked NICE!!!");
    }
});
```

Comment: @LocDaiLe sure! Also have a look at Daniel's answer regarding name formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Field names should always start with an underscore or a lowercase letter. Class names start with uppercase letters.

When you declare a new variable, then you have to specify it's type (class) and name, in this order.

To fix your code, change your first line to:

```
Button declineBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.declineBTN);
```

So your `declineBtn` local variable is a `Button`. 
And then in your second line also change the name to start with a lowercase letter:

```
declineBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
```